# Unable to print the user input values of formatted HTML in active choice parameter in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have been trying to capture the values that user has input from jenkins using active choice parameters. Below is my snippet

```
if(DB_CREATION.equals("yes")){
                                FullHTML = """
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">IP</label>
                                <input name='IP' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input> <br></p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">USERNAME</label>
                                <input name='USERNAME' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">PASSWORD</label>
                                <input name='PASSWORD' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_NAME</label>
                                <input name='DB_NAME' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_PASSWORD</label>
                                <input name='DB_PASSWORD' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                """
                                return FullHTML    }
                                else if(DB_CREATION.equals("no")){
                                FullHTML = """
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">IP</label>
                                <input name='IP' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input> <br></p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">USERNAME</label>
                                <input name='USERNAME' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">PASSWORD</label>
                                <input name='PASSWORD' type='text' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                """
                                return FullHTML 
                                }
```

Pipeline Snippet would look like below -

```
[$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', description: '', name: 'PARAMETERS', omitValueField: false, randomName: 'choice-parameter-20993075376134551', referencedParameters: 'DB_CREATION', script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: 'return[\'Would not be possible to Proceed Further\']'], script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: '''if(DB_CREATION.equals("yes")){
                                FullHTML = """
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">IP</label>
                                <input name=\'IP\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input> <br></p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">USERNAME</label>
                                <input name=\'USERNAME\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">PASSWORD</label>
                                <input name=\'PASSWORD\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_NAME</label>
                                <input name=\'MC_DB_NAME\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_PASSWORD</label>
                                <input name=\'MC_DB_PASSWORD\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                               
                                """
                                return FullHTML    }
                                else if(DB_CREATION.equals("no")){
                                FullHTML = """
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">IP</label>
                                <input name=\'IP\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input> <br></p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">USERNAME</label>
                                <input name=\'USERNAME\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">PASSWORD</label>
                                <input name=\'PASSWORD\' type=\'text\' class="setting-input" name="value"> </input><br>
                                </p>
                                """
                                return FullHTML 
                                }''']]]
```

And i am trying to print like below -(Possible prints) -

```
  echo '${params.FullHTML}'
                echo '${params.PARAMETERS}'
                echo "${params.PARAMETERS}"
                echo "${params.FullHTML}"
```

And i am trying to print like above
All are either passing null or nothing. HOw to extract user input and pass them to my test suite?